# Copy a file from one folder to another folder and rename the file in the new folder with old filename+timestamp

Tags: java

I want to copy a word document from one folder to another folder. In the new folder the file name should be oldFileName+timeStamp.
I have come so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

    File source = new File("C:\\Users\\rr\\test\\XYZ.docx");        
    File destination=new File("C:\\Users\\rr\\XYZ.docx");
    FileUtils.copyFile(source,destination);
    // copy from folder 'test' to folder 'rr'

   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss");
   String ts=sdf.format(source.lastModified());
    String outFileName = destination.getName() + ts ;
    //appending ts to the file name
    System.out.println(" new file name is "+outFileName);

      }
```

I am able to copy the file from folder test to folder rr but the file name remains the same. How can I change this new file name to oldFileName+timeStamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating the new name of the file first, then copy it...

Don't forget, you need to separate the name and extension, so you can insert the time stamp between them...

```
File source = new File("C:\\Users\\rr\\test\\XYZ.docx");

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss");
String ts = sdf.format(source.lastModified());
String name = source.getName();
String ext = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));
String outFileName = name + " " + ts + ext;
//appending ts to the file name
System.out.println(" new file name is " + outFileName);

File destination = new File("C:\\Users\\rr", outFileName);
```

For example, this will create a file in `C:\Users\rr` named `XYZ 01-01-1970 10-00-00.docx` (I don't have the original file, so the date is `0`)

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    File source = new File("C:\\Users\\rr\\test\\XYZ.docx");    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss");
    String ts=sdf.format(source.lastModified());
    File destination=new File("C:\\Users\\rr\\XYZ"+ts+".docx");
    FileUtils.copyFile(source,destination);
    System.out.println(" new file name is "+outFileName);
}
```